# flagging a chatroom which has no technical discussion (2)

Tags: support, chat

Since [my comment yesterday](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135344/flagging-a-chatroom-which-has-no-technical-discussion/135380#comment391856_135380) to [an answer by Jeff](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/135380/133368) to the [question with the very same title](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/135344/133368) seems to have gone unnoticed, I feel the need to post this officially.

According to [Jeff's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/135380/133368), [that room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/11726/yarron-ki-mehfil) was closed because "there appears to be zero programming discussion in it." Note that the room's tagline was

> Rule #1: Enter the room, Introduce yourself, with Gender Rule #2: No Technical discussion here Rule #3: Break all the rules and enjoy the life :P (if better is possible, good is not enough..)

Yesterday, some message was flagged which I looked closer at, and it came from [this room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/9845/friends-forever), which turned out to have ***the very same tagline***. I can't help but assume that it exists for the same (wrong) reasons as the one that was closed.

Comment: [This chat room is not a room where people are exclusively to discuss any professional, theoretical, or whatever problem thrown at them by whoever comes by. It's called "Lounge" for a reason: The room's goal is to be a place for SO's C++ programmers to hang out, chat, and recreate. And it's pretty damn successful at achieving that goal. Per agenda, almost anything is on topic in this room, including, but not limited to, math, sex, drugs, and C++.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/134407/162704)

Comment: Educated guess: The room that was closed, wasn't closed because it had no technical discussion, but because some (most?) of the discussions were deemed inappropriate. Since a lot of the discussions in the new room are in a language I don't know, I have no idea what's going on in there and whether this room should be closed as was the previous one. The tagline alone, however, strongly hints that this room also needs to be looked closely by the moderators...

Comment: @Yannis: That, or something similar, has been said about the C++ room quite often. Always, though, was "C++" included as a possible topic of the room. And, surprisingly, C++ discussions indeed do come up in the C++ room. As well as discussions about Java, .NET, Python (just an hour ago), operating systems (right now), and whatnot. The lounge's purpose is _not_ to never talk about programming, it's to be a place where programmers hang out. So it's a wild mix. We keep repeating the "sex, drugs, and C++" tagline because users come there when they are too lazy to write a question for SO proper.

Comment: @Yannis: As for what the room I pointed out is all about: I only speak German and English, so I don't know, really, whether the room's topics are appropriate or not. That's why I am asking for support here, after all. I only noticed that this is a room with the very same tagline as the one that was closed down for being totally off-topic, so I thought I'd better ask.

Comment: Hope you realize my first comment wasn't exactly serious, was fooling around a bit. As for the closed room, I'm _not_ convinced it was closed (only) for being totally off topic, whatever Jeff says in his answer. Don't know for sure, and wouldn't/couldn't share if I did, but my spider sense is tingling, there's something more there. Perhaps a more... interesting definition of totally off topic. Anyway, the point is that the new room is worth investigating.

Comment: @Yannis: No offense taken, and I thought your statement is friendly teasing. Still, I felt the need to explain the difference, as some at meta have an, erm, _quite peculiar opinion_ about the C++ room, which I don't feel needs to be fed.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I've noticed that many users, especially Indian ones, use the chatrooms as a place to socialize (nothing related to the site/topic, just IMing), as well as to garner votes.

**Many of the users in these rooms aren't even active on SO/SE, they just chat**

Also, these rooms are usually in Romanized Hindi (or another Indic language), so the mods just leave them alone.

A few weeks back, I'd taken up the task of keeping an eye on these Indian chat rooms. We had deleted https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3688/cooking-tips, and I had found some others:

- https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6137/
- https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3739/friendly-technical-room (this one was created immediately after I deleted the cooking tips room)
- https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7337/uk-javascript
- https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10227/no-holds-barred/

(and more, but I don't have a list of those)

But I was able to find a bit of technical discussion in each, so I didn't escalate the issue.

Most of the banter in these rooms comprises of small talk, jokes, and flirting. There's a bit of technical discussion, though I dunno if it's enough to allow their existence by Jeff's rules--I feel that they just ought to be deleted..

---

Update: It's been deleted, along with the others.

---

If you find any more such rooms, please let me know in chat or in the comments here. I already have a list of these rooms, which I shall go through one by one and request deletion if necessary.

Comment: Glad to see our official Indian chat room exterminator already hard at work ;P

Comment: @YannisRizos: :P Not really hard at work, though--I slacked off from that after I found that there was _some_ technical discussion (veeery leetle though), and Jeff's criteria allowed chat rooms with a bare minimum. This list I compiled from the transcript of the chat moderation room.

Comment: *flirting*? wow

Comment: @DiscountGucciHandbags: Yes, flirting. Borders on sexual harassment sometimes. Pestering for email addys, etc as well. And loads of other stuff.

Comment: Well that's just creepy

Comment: Thanks for looking into this, Manish!

Comment: @Discount: We're talking a society here that's been preferring male fetuses over female ones for a very long time, and for decades now has access to [the medical tools to satisfy that preference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sex-selective_abortion#India). They have between 5-20% more males there than females. Of course those boys are desperate.

Comment: @sbi Unfortunately true... Though it's not just that, really, it's also how such things are tolerated in society. A girl won't complain to someone else, because such things (harassment, rape) impinge on _her_ honor. So these things, as well as their lesser forms (what we see in the chat rooms) go by unnoticed. IMO, it's not due to desperation as much as it is due to such stuff being "the norm" and tolerated.

Comment: @Manish: Yes, I believe you that this, too, is a problem. However, I was merely referring to the puzzlement that someone would attempt to flirt at SO.

Comment: *Sigh* Just to note, not everyone of indian extraction approves of such a thing. I will gladly throw a very large book if i can at such things, especially if there's a flag. There's a good bunch of users of indian extraction or from there. It isn't really a norm in *my* own culture, to the south, where we actually respect women to an extent. Please don't judge us based on these idiots :)

Comment: @JourneymanGeek: No, we're not judging everyone (I'm Indian myself). We're just saying that you see this more amongst Indians. In fact, SO has lots of problems with Indian users--bad grammar, vote rings, etc. I'm not saying that the majority of Indian users do this--I'm saying that the majority of such stuff is from Indians. Subtle difference :)

Comment: No offence taken, just wanted to point out the other side of it, and for some reason, whatever pride i have in the country of my extraction seems slightly hurt that people do these silly things ;p.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek: Same here. I can easily realize when it's an Indian doing it, and I cringe every time.

Comment: I'm all for it. Those rooms are breeding grounds for trolls.

Comment: @Manish I've edited in some more rooms to your list. Note: some of the rooms that were nuked have spawned again. [Some of the trolls](http://stackoverflow.com/users/961529/ninjaturtle) who have no legit contributions to SO should be nuked too. [This guy for example](http://stackoverflow.com/users/514945/manjotsingh) is serving a SO ban anyway

Comment: @Reno: Rest assured, I already know of most of those rooms (except two of them, thanks for that ^.^ ). But there are I also do know that many users come here just to chat, and that's part of what I'm trying to stop. (I have a list of users who are constant visitors of such rooms as well, I can use their profiles to dig out more such rooms--and keep track of the respawning). Next time, let me know via a comment or in chat (You can find me here: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3229/). Also: good catch about ninjaturtle, he's been called out before. I let an so mod know :)

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13703/techs-n-talkz

Comment: @Lucifer: I already have that one.

Comment: @Reno & Manish: That NinjaTurtle guy [has caused](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/137744/133368) [suspicion before](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/138481/how-can-i-request-for-close-of-chat-room).

Comment: @Journeyman: I am sorry if this came across harsh. I am with Manish on that, where he says "I'm not saying that the majority of Indian users do this — I'm saying that the majority of such stuff is from Indians". I do feel your pain, though. Being a German, I cringe every time somebody says "grammar nazi".

Comment: @ManishEarthwantsmorewaffles here's one http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13675/ seems to have been set up expressly to taunt bolt after he shut down one of the owners' other rooms.

Comment: @ManishEarthwantsmorewaffles And this one http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13396/silverlight-wpf which seems to be where the crowd from UK_Javascript have migrated to.

Comment: @ManishEarthwantsmorewaffles A strange one that has a couple of questions now and again. Mostly repeats but is basically chat. http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/13976/ios-android

Comment: @TheReader Thanks. Gone now.

Answer (score 2):

I've noticed that some of the rooms have started to be closed. However, there is a corollary effect:

Some rooms have been plagued in the past by users who just come into the rooms to chat, disrupt and troll. In the past couple of months this hasn't been happening because they've moved on to these content-free rooms.

Now that the spurious rooms are starting to be closed - they are coming back into the technical rooms and dropping the signal to noise ratio.

I feel what is really needed is a policy of what constitutes disruptive behaviour in a chat room and some sort of sanction.

Or at least some kind of community guidance on how to deal with them.

Comment: I felt the same need; we now have an official policy http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139362/definitive-rules-on-chat-rooms-with-non-technical-discussion/139382#139382. Please refer users to that if they are plaguing your room with OT chats (again, a bit of OT chat is OK--but the users shouldn't be there just for OT chat). Also, if you feel that a deleted/frozen room was of the constructive-if-a-few-people-weren't-there type, let a mod know. Note that in my cleanup, I _am_ trying to identify such rooms and exclude them(instead of requesting deletion, I'll just notify the involved users)