# Chat flagging is out of control

Tags: support, flags, chat

In [room 10](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10/loungec) of Stack Overflow we have had a troll (or multiple trolls) for the past few weeks casting random flags and generally being disruptive.

[image]

Today for example I woke up to this.

For us or room owners there's no way to handle this kind of disruptive behaviour, and moderators cannot help either, given that they can't be online all the time (as it appears to be the case today).

Also [warnings](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/25477301#25477301) don't seem to work very well.

What should we do?

---

On a side note I see that we also have a similar problem [with stars](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qasrg.png) (image by [@Mr. kbok](https://stackoverflow.com/users/361535/mr-kbok)).

Comment: And I would like to thank @JonClements for all the work he's done for us so far. Unfortunately, his last name isn't Skeet and he isn't online 24/7.

Comment: Flag trolls are the thing I hate most, even more than spammers. IMO moderator should chat ban all of them for at least one year.

Comment: We went from flag spamming to [star spamming](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Qasrg.png), and I can't even do anything as room owner as I got banned by the silly flagger. :(

Comment: One flagger can't ban you. If you got banned, you might wanna ask why anyone else gave credence to the flagger's nonsense, @Tony...

Comment: I think convincing Mysticial to mod is probably the best idea here.

Comment: @Shog9 even so, it's complete waste of time for mods and 10k users who have to dismiss those flags

Comment: @Shog9 If you want some more context, take a look at the mod room that Jon had with us. This has been going on for a while now.

Comment: Well, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/203346/flags-in-chat-are-defective-by-design

Comment: I'm a regular of the room 10 and I agree with the above, we haven't identified the flagger/spammer but [it seems Jon has](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/25477301#25477301). I recommend contacting him first.

Comment: Jon is continuing to dig into this; I highly recommend working with him (and, not to belabor the point but, posting *actually offensive stuff* while you're trying to ferret out a flag-spammer is counter productive, so...)

Comment: I enjoy getting flagged on a regular basis at around 9-10 am.

Comment: Seems to have happened in [Mathematics](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36/mathematics) just now

Answer (score 1):

Flag for a mod to intervene and investigate.

The chat "offensive" flag system has always been dubious. There's nothing else to do about it until it's improved.

Comment: Rejecting doesn't work. I've run out of "counter-flags" several times while trying to suppress the flags in the Lounge. It seems there's no limit to flagging, but a limit to counter-flagging.

Comment: Oh, my bad. There is a limit to starring, but not flagging.

Comment: Actually, mods can't see who the flagger is once the flag is cleared. So it's better to just take no action. Let the flag live for as long as possible until a mod sees it. Yes. Believe it or not, the system encourages us to keep bad flags around...